# Why is my git commands not in english?

Tags: git

My git answers in french despite the fact that I don't have any LC_ALL, LANG, LC_*  env vars defined. Happens in zsh, bash on osx, qwerty keyboard layout.

This only happens for git afaik, usual shell commands are all in english.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may add this line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to force git to English:

```
alias git='LANG=en_US git'
```

Or you might need to use:

```
alias git='LC_ALL=en_US git'
```

When added to `~/.bashrc`, the alias will be defined for new interactive shells
only. Add it to `~/.bash_profile` to be applied after log in.

Comment: This may help but the explicit question is "why?". It remains unanswered.

Comment: "Why" is usually because the program misinterprets some system settings. For example on Windows you may have as your system language English USA but choose European settings for monetary units etc. Some programs use the wrong API call and choose the wrong language (happened to me). I have seen reports of git users that had to expunge every reference on the computer to a non-English language to get rid of this problem.

Comment: wouldn't  LC_ALL and LANG have unforeseen effects on other softwares? I'd rather identified the other "every reference on the computer"

Comment: The way this is done, it only has effect for git. Other programs are not affected.